# Streaming data to BigQuery from FCM/Firebase Performance

Tags: google-bigquery

I know that it's possible to stream data from Crashlytics and Google Analytics to BigQuery.

I'm using nowadays standard (batch) data export for FCM and Firebase Performance's data.

My problem is I'd like to switch from batch export to streaming export for FCM and Performance but I couldn't find anything in docs about it. Does it mean that it's not possible?

For Crashlytics and GA there are simple checkbox to turn on streaming but there are none for FCM and Performance.

I'd be grateful for any help/information about it.